# css3 to stack 2 background images on the body

Tags: css

I would like to use 2 images as a fixed image's background image so I used the code on the body.

```
background: url(images/31.jpg) 100% no-repeat, url(images/12.jpg) 100% no-repeat;
background-position: fixed;
```

I need them to fit the browser width 100% and I want image 2 to stack vertically after image 1. I have read quite a few websites about using multiple images with CSS3. Is this possible without JavaScript and if so why do my images stack on top of one another and image 1 doesn't start at top left?

Answer (score 0):

> the following reference css try it

```
#idName {
  background-image: url(image1.png),url(image2.png);
  background-position: center bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: it just shows 1 image, not the 2nd.  the rest of the page is white.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the vertical size to 50% or so, else every images takes all the height

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/150), url(http://placekitten.com/200/120);
    background-size: auto 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center, bottom center;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLAB3/)

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work.  When I delete the auto from the background size I can see one image, but if I add the auto to the background size I get a blank page

Comment: I have test the fiddle in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11. What browser are you using ? Also, if you change the auto, set it to 100%:   background-size: 100% 50%;

Comment: when adding body, html {height: 100%;}  to the code it now works.  strange

Comment: I included this code in the fiddle, but didn't show it in the answer, because I understood that you had already some dimension set to body. Probably you had the body height to 0, and because of that you didn't see the body background (or anything else in the body, for that matter)